# Best fit of weighted mean?

Tags: optimization, fitting, weighted-mean

The title might be somewhat misleading. I am trying to solve the following optimization problem and do not find any clues. Can any one help?

I have a sequence of $n$ observation $s_i$. Each observation $s_i$ is a vector of $m$ positive real numbers ,i.e., $$\forall i\in[1,n]: \mathbf{s_i}\in\mathbb{R}^m_+$$.

Now, let $k_i$ be a sequence of $n$ scalar parameters, $k_i\in \mathbf{R}$. We define the *weighted  mean* 
$$M=\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i\in[1,n]}k_i \mathbf{s_i} $$ 
and the energy function $E(k_1,\ldots k_n)$ is defined as
 $$ E(k_1,\ldots k_n) = \Sigma_{i\in[1, n]}(k_i \mathbf{s_i}-M)^2$$
Note that each vector $\mathsf{s_i}$ is fixed here. The objective is to find $k_1,\ldots, k_n$ such that $E(k_1\ldots, k_n)$ is minimal.

I believe this is a classic problem in math or in physics but have no well-chosen key words to guide me. Also, I was trying to solve this problem using classic least square method, but the questions seems  be less evident than this. Making a partial derivation for each $k_i$ and then solving the obtained equations turns out  be overwhelmingly complex.

This problem can be a little bit simplified, which, I am not sure, will be useful for our subsequent discussions. The problem is equivalent to find $k_1\ldots k_i$ s.t. 
$$ \Sigma_{i,j\in[1,n]}(k_i \mathbf{s_i} - k_j \mathbf{s_j})^2 $$
takes the minimal.

One may quickly find that there would be an infinity of solutions. It might be useful to explain the context of the problem: I have $20$ observed data 
$\mathbf{s_1, s_2\ldots s_{20}}$, 
each $\mathbf{s_i}$ being a vector of 100 positive numbers. These data are observed in such a way that they are proportional to the physical data, with the ratios between $s_i$ and the real data fixed and can be different for each individual data. My real problem is to normalize these observed data.

Comment: This seems similar to [locally weighted linear regression](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume4/cohn96a-html/node7.html).

Comment: Thanks. Could you be more precise?  I do not see any relationship between the two...

Comment: I think your definition of the weighted mean should be $M = \sum k_i x_i / \sum k_i$. and not $1/n$ unless the weights actually add to $n$.